# openGL ES shaders wrong uniforms location

Tags: opengl-es, location, uniform

vertex shader looks like this:

```
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColor;

varying vec4 vDestinationColor;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position         = projectionMatrix * modelMatrix * viewMatrix * vPosition;
    vDestinationColor   = vColor;
}
```

Objective-C code:

```
_projectionMatrixSlot   = glGetUniformLocation(_programHandle, "projectionMatrix");
_modelMatrixSlot        = glGetUniformLocation(_programHandle, "modelMatrix");
_viewMatrixSlot         = glGetUniformLocation(_programHandle, "viewMatrix");

_positionAttribSlot     = glGetAttribLocation(_programHandle, "vPosition");
_colorAttribSlot        = glGetAttribLocation(_programHandle, "vColor");
```

here _projectionMatrixSlot  _viewMatrixSlot _modelMatrixSlot equals 4294967295
while _positionAttribSlot and _colorAttribSlot is fine

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is free to throw away variables that are not used in the code. Therefore, even if a uniform is declared in the shader, as long as it is not used, its reported location can be -1 or max int or unsigned int.

You may have attached wrong vertex shader, not this one which you post here.

Comment: i am using like this later in the code:     glUniformMatrix4fv(_projectionMatrixSlot, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&_projectionMatrix.m[0]);

Comment: again, yours uniforms was deleted from program, because was not used in main.

Comment: what about: gl_Position         = projectionMatrix * modelMatrix * viewMatrix * vPosition;

Comment: it's means you may have wrong vertex shader attached, not this one which you post here

Comment: thank you so much I delete app from simulator and run it again and it works, the shader source probably read from somewhere else, again thanks.

Comment: @user2953401 it's sometimes happens with simulator, it may did not update some files.